# Crystal report 2013 not displaying Oracle Server

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I have Oracle 11 installed. I recently installed Crystal Reports 2013. However, I do not see Oracle Server listed when I try to create a new connection. I am not sure why. Please suggest me.

Thanks,
Roshni

Comment: Why am I getting negative points for my question? I was hoping someone could help me understand what could have been wrong, or how I could get the Oracle Server under new connection.

Comment: I guess it just needed someone with the same problem.  :/  Except with CR 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have Oracle Client for Crystal Report to connect to the Oracle database. Once I installed a 32 bit oracle client, I was able to see Oracle Server as a option in the Connections.

I wanted to let you all know so that if somebody is stuck like me, they can benefit from this answer.

Thanks again!